# Assembler - Работа с файлами

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Нужно привести простой пример создания файла на Fasm, желательно с комментариями

Comment: В чем же ваша проблема? Что не получается?

Comment: Пытаюсь создать txt файл, не могу найти нормальной  инструкции, описания команд

Comment: @Максим А нет специальной инструкции "создать txt файл".

Answer (score 2):

В ассемблере нет команд для работы с файлами. Для того, чтобы что-то сделать с файлом, нужен драйвер файловой системы. Работа с файловой системой, как правило, обёрнута в api операционной системы. В Windows это делается при помощи функции [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

PS: Потом добавлю пример, если найду.

Comment: @Abyx, тьфу.. CreateFile - исправил.